# javascript for loop counter coming out as string

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I've simplified my program down to this, and it's still misbehaving:

```
var grid = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function moveUp(moveDir) {
    for (var row in grid) {
        console.log('row:');
        console.log(row + 5);
    }
}
```

It seems that `row` is a string instead of an integer, for example the output is

```
row:
05
row:
15
row:
25
row:
35
```

rather than 5, 6, 7, 8, which is what I want. Shouldn't the counter in the for loop be a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22448330/1903116?

Comment: Not enough information

Comment: @thefourtheye rather a duplicate of [When iterating over values, why does typeof(value) return “string” when value is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933737/1048572)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN Docs of `for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description),

> **`for..in` should not be used to iterate over an `Array` where index order
>   is important.** Array indexes are just enumerable properties with
>   integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
>   properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the
>   indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
>   properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
>   inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
>   or the non-standard [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop) when iterating over arrays where
>   the order of access is important.

You are iterating an array with `for..in`. That is bad. When you iterate with `for..in`, what you get is the array indices in string format.

So on every iteration, `'0' + 5 == '05'`, `'1' + 5 == '15'`... is getting printed

What you should be doing is,

```
for (var len = grid.length, i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    console.log('row:');
    console.log(grid[i] + 5);
}
```

For more information about why exactly array indices are returned in the iteration and other interesting stuff, please check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22448330/1903116)

Comment: +1. I knew that loop was bad for arrays, I just didn't know why.

Comment: @Andy Two days back I had a similar question and explained in deep this behaviour. Please check the linked answer in this answer. :)

Comment: I guess it makes perfect sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a normal `for` loop rather than a `for...in` loop for arrays.

```
for (var row = 0, l = grid.length; row < l; row++) {
  console.log('row:');
  console.log(5 + row);
}
```

I think this is what your expected output should be.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/tryu3/)

Answer (score -1):

Try with parseInt(..) method to force int value

```
console.log(parseInt(row,10) + 5);
```

second param 10 is to be parsed as decimal value.

See the answer here [How do I add an integer value with javascript (jquery) to a value that's returning a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460172/how-do-i-add-an-integer-value-with-javascript-jquery-to-a-value-thats-returni)