# Why Object.keys is returns array of string instead of array of Numbers

Tags: javascript

When I run following code

```
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
typeof Object.keys(obj)[0] //returns string
```

In `obj` object i'm creating Number keys.

Any reason, why its string and not a `number`?

Comment: You can't have numeric keys for object properties. Object properties are always strings.

Comment: if you need numbers as keys use ES2015 `Map`

Comment: But we can do by `obj[0]` also, where `0` is number,
I just want to know any particular reason that they treated in this way

Comment: I guess answers missing my question,
I don't want workaround,
Is `javascript community` made mistake when making `Object.keys` function?

Comment: `0` is typecast to string.

Comment: See also [Is JavaScript array index a string or an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27537677/1048572)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array with strings

> `Object.keys()` returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually.

You get an array of strings, because [Property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Property_names) are strings by definition.

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method.

Comment: @pvg,  while *`toString` is not a cast, it returns a string representation of any object. Including strings.* is true, mdn stated above.

Comment: Ah it makes more sense as a quote now. It's still, despite the MDN provenance,  completely wrong, it's a conversion, not a cast even without the nitpicky complaint that 'typecasted' is not grammatically correct English.

Answer (score 40):

Keys are **always** of a String type. If you need numbers you will have to cast them manually:

```js
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
var ids = Object.keys(obj).map(Number);

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Technically, they could be Symbols too, if I understand JS correctly.

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation **[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Description)** returns string array

> **Object.keys()** returns an array whose elements are ***strings*** corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually.(*[Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Description)*)

If you want to convert it to number array then use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var obj = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c'
};
console.log(typeof Object.keys(obj).map(Number)[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Object has no number keys! All keys are Strings. Always.

If you want to map other things to values you should use a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Just some type safety to be careful of with some of the higher rated answers here (like `Object.keys(obj).map(Number)`) there are a lot of edge cases in .js where you may get false positive results if you map to `Number`). Not so much when working with object keys, but there are always oddities like why is `Number([])` === `0`...

In this `Object.keys()` example, if you have an object with mixed types that don't safely cast to a numeric type, you'll end up casting everything to `NaN`:

```
Object.keys({ "a": "1", 2: "2" }).map(Number) 
// -> [NaN, 2]
// :(
```

You can get a little fancy with the map method, and it will gracefully handle non-numeric keys:

```
Object.keys({ "a": "1", 2: "2" }).map((k) => Number.isNaN(Number(k)) ? k : Number(k)
// -> ["a", 2]
// :)
```