# What is the difference between using a string or a number to index an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, integer

In Javascript it is possible to use a number (integer) or a string (or a char) to index an array for example:

```
array[0] = true;
```

**or**

```
array['0'] = true;
```

Does the computer memory work different depending on how you index the array or is it the exact same thing to do it both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes are stored internally as strings.
But it's more common practise to use numbers to access an array by it's index.

> A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if
>   and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not
>   equal to 2^³²−1

It's explained in [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537677/)

Below is a snippet that showcases it.
Accessing the index with a string works fine as long that index string only contains digits.
But by expressing the index as a word then it can only be accessed with that word. And console logging the array doesn't show it.

```js
let arr = [0,'a one','a two','a three'];
arr['four'] = 'a four';
arr.push('5');
arr.push(6);
arr.push([7,'7']);
arr.push({a:8, b:'8'});


console.log('\nLog the array:\n\n');
console.log(arr);

console.log('\nAccessing the array:\n\n');
console.log("arr[0]:\t" + arr[0]);
console.log("arr[\'1\']:\t" + arr['1']);
console.log("arr[\'two\']:\t" + arr['two']);
let i=2;
console.log("arr[++i]:\t" + arr[++i]);
console.log("arr[\'four\']:\t" + arr['four']);
console.log('arr[4]:\t'+ arr[4]);
console.log('arr[5]:\t'+ arr[5]);

console.log('\nListing the types in the array:\n\n');
for (var a in arr) console.log(a+'\tindex type: '+ typeof a +', value: '+ arr[a] + ', value type: '+ typeof arr[a]);
```

And here's a snippet to compare speed between using a number or a string in your browser.  It should take roughly the same time.

```js
let arr1 = [];
console.time('Access array through string');
for(let i = 0; i <= 42000000;i++){
 arr1['42000000'] = 42;
}
console.timeEnd('Access array through string');

let arr2 = [];
console.time('Access array through integer');
for(let i = 0; i <= 42000000;i++){
 arr2[42000000] = 42;
}
console.timeEnd('Access array through integer');
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: **there is no difference.**

Javascript arrays are objects. All keys of objects are **strings** (or symbols), but never numbers.

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects
>   cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including
>   a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method. *[...see more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names)*

The property accessor `[]` converts to `string` first before looking for the property. (some engines may optimize this step and not perform a proper `toString` call, but it's of no concern here)

So `array[0]` is interpreted as `array['0']`.

```js
const a = {
    toString: function () {
        console.log("a.toString called")
        return "1";
    }
};

const array = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(array[a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use quotations for indexing, you're creating a key-value pair in the array. I recommended you stick to numerical notation unless you're intentionally creating those pairs; while `array['0']` technically posts to the position, it's bad practice.

Even though `myArr['two']` doesn't seem to want to show up in the snippet output, if you hit `F12` and look at the console output, you'll clearly see it displayed.

> `["String 0", "String 1", two: "String 2"]`

```js
let myArr = [];
myArr[0] = "String 0";
myArr['1'] = "String 1";
myArr['two'] = "String 2";

console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what's going to happen if you're using a string that does not evaluate to a number.

Comment: Arrays are already objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Why when you use a string that does not equal a number you can't see it when calling the whole array, but when calling it specific like this myArr['two'] it does show up?

Answer (score 0):

As the mdn docs state, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Arrays are actually just objects that have array-like properties. Keys in JavaScript are strings. So when you see an array, it's actually just a set of key-value pairs, where the keys are index numbers.

Arrays are a special data type. Adding keys that do not correlate to possible indexes are added to an 'object property collection' and are not returned when you use the object.

I think the chrome console does the best job of displaying this:

This array is actually an object with keys of `0 1 2 3`, a `length` property, and a prototype.

[image]