# Why does a number as key worked for a string key in an Object and vice-versa (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Curious about the following two cases:

**First:**

```
const key = 2;
const obj = { "2": "stackoverflow" };
obj[key]; //results in "stackoverflow" but the key is 2 and not "2"
```

**Second:**

```
//Vice versa case
const otherKey = "21";
const otherObj = { 21: "youtube" };
otherObj[otherKey]; //results in "youtube" but the key is "21" and not 21
```

**My conclusion:**

That since keys should be string and while finding `key` (when key is seemingly a number) existence in Javascript objects it does so by **type-conversion** comparison and not by **strict** or a **string conversion**.

Is there more to this why these cases work and am more interested in the how bit of that?

Comment: Object keys are always strings. When you use a number as getter/setter it will automatically be cast to string

Comment: @charlietfl, btw, symbols are allowed as well.

Comment: @charlietfl +1 that makes sense because in JS keys must be string. Any documentation that you can point me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant bits of the standard are

> [12.3.2.1 Runtime Semantics:
>   Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
>
> MemberExpression:MemberExpression[Expression]
>
> ...6. Let propertyKey be ? ToPropertyKey(propertyNameValue).

and

> [7.1.14 ToPropertyKey ( argument )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-topropertykey)
>
> 1. Let key be ? ToPrimitive(argument, hint String).
> 2. If Type(key) is Symbol, then Return key.
> 3. Return ! ToString(key).

In plain English, in `object[whatever]`, `whatever` is converted to a string, unless it's a `symbol`.

Illustration:

```js
let s = Symbol();

let o = { 
  '12': 1,
  'foo': 2,
  'true': 3,
  [s]: 4
}

console.log(o[6*2])
console.log(o[{toString: () => 'foo'}])
console.log(o[1 === 1])
console.log(o[s])
```

The behaviour of object initializers is described in [12.2.6.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is something called [type coercion](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/), where a value of one type is converted to some other type for doing some operation using said value.

Since objects in Javascript store keys and values, and the keys are stored as strings, when you provide a numeric value as the key to the object, it is coerced to a string and then looked up in the object.

It'd be a little clearer if we took the example of an array. Arrays store values at indexes, which are numeric. So if we have `var a = [4, 3, 5]`, looking up the value at index `2` using a `a[2]` and `a["2"]` would give you the same result `5`, since the string `"2"` is coerced to a `number` type to support the lookup operation in the array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Arrays' indexes are strings as well. In fact, Arrays don't treat indexes in any special way.

Comment: See [Is JavaScript array index a string or an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27537677/1048572)

Comment: They do, actually. If we assign some array and later add another value at a much larger new index, the length property will show the number one greater than the largest we just used. That said, since everything in JS is an object we CAN add properties to arrays as well, same as we can for other objects.

Comment: The exotic behaviour of the `.length` property doesn't matter here. Semantically (i.e. ignoring runtime optimisations), array indices are strings like all other property names.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) here

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

So, basically the keys are type coerced to strings even if they are numbers.

```js
const object = { 21 : 'test', '21': 'message' };

console.log(object)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: JSON was created based on javascript objects ....not the other way around

Comment: @DhananjaiPai But here I am not using `JSON.stringify` and I am pretty sure finding `key` existence would not involve atleast converting it by `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I was just saying that Javascript objects store keys as strings and do not differentiate between numbers and strings since JSON was modelled as a serialization mechanism for Javascript Objects and would have factored for "numeric" keys if it was already a language feature!

Comment: @ambianBeing Any mention of JSON in this answer is completely irrelevant. It has nothing to do with how the javascript engines manage objects